# Flask Python - Google Chart javascript is not working passing string as parameter in html page

Tags: python, flask, charts, google-visualization

I have this string in my flask app.

[image]

I am passing this string for my google chart in page, but its not working. Somebody could help me?
[image]

My javascript and HTML page
[image]

Comment: Please add your code as text, not as an image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`arrayToDataTable` expects an array, not a string.

you could parse the string as JSON...

```
JSON.parse(my_string)

var data2 = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(JSON.parse(my_string));
```

but first, you will need to change **all** the single quotes...

```
['Month',  ...
```

to double quotes...

```
["Month",  ...
```

Comment: will you please check the browser's console for errors? (press F12)

Comment: Error:monitor_peers:263 Uncaught (in promise) ReferenceError: my_string is not defined
    at drawVisualization (monitor_peers:263)

Comment: so `my_String` is not defined, the data isn't being passed to the page properly...

Comment: I fix the errr of my_string os not definied. But now the error is  Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '&'. In the borwser Sources the error is inthe line: var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(JSON.parse([[&#34;Month&#34;, &#34;Geral&#34;, &#34;Fundos&#34;, &#34;Prev&#34;, &#34;Renda Fixa&#34;, &#34;Meta&#34;],[&#34;201912&#34;,81.9,81.9,81.9,81.9,85.0],[&#34;202001&#34;,71.8,71.8,71.8,71.8,85...

Comment: looks like the data is being encoded. there's probably a content type heading / setting you need to set in flask somewhere, ideally you would want to set it to JSON. then you probably wouldn't need to use the parse method I suggested. but i'm not familiar with flask

Comment: It was a encoding problem like you said. I Solved the problem. In Flask-Jinja there is a filter named safe. My code: var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable({{my_string|safe}})